# What is the best way to access non-type template parameters from other classes?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14

I have a container class and other parts of my code need access to its non-type template parameters. You can't access non-type template parameters with the :: operator, so what is be the preferred method of getting at those values?

This minimal code example contains the three methods which I know of:

```
#include <iostream>

template<int N>
struct Container 
{
    enum{Size = N};
    static const int m_size = N;
    constexpr int size() {return N;} //c++11
}; 

int main() {
    Container<42> c;

    //Output all three methods of getting N
    std::cout<< "::Size = " << Container<42>::Size << '\n';
    std::cout<< "m_size = " << c.m_size << '\n';
    std::cout<< "size() = " << c.size() << '\n';
}
```

Compiling with GCC-4.9 (unsurprisingly) gives:

```
::Size = 42
m_size = 42
size() = 42
```

All three of these methods *work*, but is there any difference in performance, or in terms of how well the compiler can optimize code?

In my particular application, the non-type template parameters are *frequently* used for things like array declarations or arithmetic functions. They are known at compile time, but not at design time. As a result, I want the compiler to make the best use of the information that these values are fixed, but I don't want to hard-code them deep in the source files somewhere, hence the choice of template parameters.

Comment: `m_size` in an expression is an lvalue, but you have not provided a definition (out of class). You therefore cannot bind it to a reference, or in any other way odr-use it.

Comment: @dyp So for an `static const int` there is a difference between an out-of-class and in-class definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solutions are mostly *equivalent*.

- `enum` is the C++03 way (and its type is no longer `int`).
- constexptr function may be call at runtime (in a non constexpr context).
- `static const` need an outside definition if address is taken

I would use a variant of case 2, though:

```
template<int N>
struct Container 
{
    static constexpr int m_size = N;
};
```

Comment: I know for `double` only the `constexpr` is valid, but is there any semantic difference between a `static constexpr int` and a `static const int`?

Comment: @Manik: `constexpr` doesn't require outside definition.

Comment: @Jarod42 Nope, [it does if odr-used](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ccccbb4432c7c356), just like `const`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no performance consideration here at all. You could measure it, but it's pretty trivial to reason that all three programs will compile identically.

In terms of style I prefer the `static const int` member. It really is completely up to you, though. Go for design consistency.